# Flutter convert string to color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to convert a string to a color value in flutter.

Here is my code:

```
Text(color,
   style: TextStyle(
      color: color.substring(1, color.length()-1),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
   ),),
```

And this is the code where I generate the color:

```
for(var item in json.decode(conversation!.idReceiversGroup!)){
                                if(!bubbleColor.map((e) => e.idUser).contains(item)){
                                  bubbleColor.add(BubbleColor(idUser: item, Color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]));
                                }
                              }
```

Is there a way to convert `substring(5, colorStr.length - 1)` to color value?

Comment: Hello aufa what do you exact want? I think you want change the color of text by index, I am correct?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to change the color based on the color I generate. Please have a look at the question, I've updated the code where I generate the color

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
  }
```

Comment: Since Dart 2 you can omit the `new` keywoard.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.  I think you want change the color of text by index.

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 20,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'data',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Your result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
Color hexToColor(String code) {
    return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may work

```
Color colorString(String? color) {
  if (color == "null" || color == null) {
    return Colors.blue;  //any color for default value
  } else {
    return Color(int.parse(color.replaceAll("#", "0xff")));
  }
}
```